# Format system and preserve RAID

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, format, raid-5

I have a system on an SSD, and beside that, a set of 4 disks are connected over software RAID 5.

I have a problem with that system now and I'd like to format that system and install a new one. If I remove the 4 drives and then format the system and install the new one, would be a problem to restore the system later?

The current system I have is Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Another question: How can I restore my drives after formatting?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using for RAID? Linux md?

Comment: @Icydog Yes, md.

Comment: What's in `/etc/mdadm.conf`?

Comment: @Icydog There's 1 array defined there: ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=......... name=Somename:0. Beside that there are some other lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the md configuration will be in `/etc/mdadm.conf` (`/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` for Ubuntu), with a line like:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid5 num-devices=4 UUID=49c5ac74:c2b79501:5c28cb9c:16a6dd9f
```

You'll probably want to save this and copy it over to the new system. But even if you don't, the metadata for the array is stored on the array disks themselves, so even if you lose the config file (say, your boot drive fails), you can just do:

```
mdadm --detail --scan
```

That will produce the appropriate configuration line. You can also do this to bring up the array:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```